# display: none; not working twice

Tags: html, css

Alright, I've been working with html/css for nearly a decade now, and for the life of me, I just can't seem to figure out why this won't work.

Initially, I was having trouble getting two separate `div`s to have `display: none` along with other properties, on page load. After troubleshooting I ended up with the conclusion that it was something wrong in the bootstrap files, so after over an hour of reducing, I simplified it to the following to remove all possible sources of error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>

#first {
    display: none;
}​

#second {
    display: none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

   <div id="first" >abc</div>
   <div id="second">123</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I saved this as `test.html` and opened it through firefox only to see:

```
123
```

I check with 'Inspect element', and sure enough, #first has the property "display: none" but #second doesn't.

I proceeded to check this with chrome and edge and got the same results.

I found that using

```
#first, #second {
    display: none;
}
```

works as expected. However, I still need to add other properties to #second, thus, thinking myself clever:

```
#first, #second {
    display: none; <!--Awesome!-->
}​

#second {
    height: 100px; <!--nope-->
    width: 100px; <!--nope-->
}
```

After much repetition in an effort to get any different result, I ended up trying something that has absolutely no reason to work what-so-ever, but at this point, I stopped caring.

I proceeded to open a new document, type out the entire original `<style>...</style>` (from first code block above) and copy it from the *unsaved* document and paste it over the faulty one.

Refreshed the page, saw nothing. Checked Inspect Element, sure enough, everything was there, just with "display: none"

So my question(s) after nearly 3 hours of troubleshooting, are:

- What happened?
- Why did it happen?

Extra info:

Windows 10 Home 64-bit

Application:
Visual Studio Code

Comment: Not `<!--Awesome!-->`  but `/* Awesome! */`. You cannot use HTML comments inside styles.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a red dot after `#first` code block. Try to paste this into jsfiddle and you'll see. Removing that makes the code work as expected.

Comment: @ishaan, Good catch! I found the same defect in OPs code. and removing that extra sign makes the code proper workable.

Comment: c-smile, Yeah... it's been a long day. I only added those here for clarification, it was never in the code I ran
and @ishaan Thanks for the find, any idea how it got there in the first place?

Comment: @R3D0, I have no Idea how that might have got there. Maybe your editor added something or maybe you copied it from some website which has special characters.. I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a strange character in your CSS, which can be seen when pasting the code into jsfiddle: [image]

Remove that, or paste the CSS below:

```css
#first {
  display: none;
}
#second {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">abc</div>
<div id="second">123</div>
```

Comment: Invisible characters are the bane of my existence. Thanks! Now if only I knew why it showed up in the first place...

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that in your `<style>`, there are strange characters showing in the Firefox Style Editor, right after the closing `}` of `#first {`. I am guessing that this confused the browsers to not process `#second` at all.

Weird though that these characters (shown as `â€‹` in Firefox) don't show up in my text editor either...

...replacing the line with the `}` with a newly typed one solved the problem however.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/horuskol/d198gqng/ < was about to post an answer - you can see the weird character in the fiddle CSS editor window (that's a straight copy/paste from the OP)

Answer (score 2):

Been there!

I tried your examples by copying/pasting to a JSFiddle and in fact you have extraneous characters after the #first closure bracket.

Just get rid of that char, and you're done.   Might be a good idea to check your text editor.  I always enable invisible characters while coding, to prevent these type of issues.

What is actually happening is that the browser CSS processor dies after the #first closure bracket, and nothing after that is processed.  Thats why #second does not seem to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/sbnyg2ev/

```
#first {
    display: none;
}​ <--- just delete that char, is not a space.

#second {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: oddly enough, in Visual Studio Code, that 'not a space' doesn't even show up. deleting from the end of `none;` through the `#` before `second` and retyping it all didn't even fix it... might be time to switch editors... again.

Comment: A couple years ago. I'll try it again and see how it goes